# Can you render arbitrary HTML in each cell of a YUI datatable?

Tags: javascript, yui

I want to add paginated table to a page.  It should be 2 rows by 4 columns.  Each cell contains a thumbnail image and some small links.

We're using YUI elsewhere on the project, so I'd like to use the Datatable.  All the examples I see are geared around tabular data (understandable), but my hunch is that I can rewrite the HTML of each cell using Javascript.  I don't see the callback function I should hook to rewrite the cells.

Possible?  Or am I trying to hammer in a nail with a screwdriver?  If there's a simpler way to do this with YUI I'd love to hear about it.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jcooper,

To paginate a simple grid of image/text elements, I'd almost prefer to see you use the Paginator without using DataTable.  DataTable is a powerful component, but it's working hard to be a lot of things you don't need.

Carousel (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/carousel/ ), on the other hand, seems like it's trying to be just what you want.  http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/carousel/csl_imagentext.html , for example, might be a good place to start.

If that's not quite what you want, you could definitely do this with DataTable.  Just create the markup snippets you want to use for each cell, store them in an array, and follow the directions for using an array datasource and pagination.

Regards,
Eric

Comment: Going through my old questions. I believe we ended up using the Paginator without the DataTable as suggested by Eric.